# How can I filter out the rows which contain a particular column with null or empty data in SQL?

Tags: sql

In SQL, How we make a check to filter all row which contain a column data is null or empty ?
For examile

```
Select Name,Age from MEMBERS
```

We need a check Name should not equal to null or empty.

Comment: Try to specify which RDBMS you are using - and select an answer :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This will work in all sane databases (*wink, wink*) and will return the rows for which name is not null nor empty

```
select name,age from members where name is not null and name <> ''
```

Comment: It doesn't work for Oracle (which is a bit odd about empty strings and nulls, admittedly).

Comment: The `IS NOT NULL` is actually likely redundant here, as `name <> ''` should filter `NULL` values implicitly. This is because `NULL <> ''` evaluates to UNKNOWN, which from a Boolean logic perspective *isn't* TRUE.

Answer (score 5):

For DBMSs that treat '' as a value (not null), Vinko's query works:

```
select name,age from members where name is not null and name <> ''
```

For Oracle, which treats '' as a null, tha above doesn't work but this does:

```
select name,age from members where name is not null
```

I tried to think of a "DBMS-agnostic" solution, but failed - mainly due to the different concatenation operators/functions used by different DBMSs!

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT Name,Age FROM MEMBERS WHERE name IS NOT null OR name <> ''`

You can get more informations from http://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp

Comment: I think you mean where name is NOT null AND name != ''; don't you?

Answer (score 0):

nvl(Name, 'some dumb string') this will return Name if Name is not null and different of '' (oracle, don't know for others). It will be equal to 'some dumb string' if null or equal to ''.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the Database being used; try
Select Name, Age from Members
where name IS NOT NULL

if you need to filter the otherway
Select Name, Age from Members
where name IS NULL

Certain RDBMS treat enpty string different from null, and you would need to add;
Select Name, Age from Members
where Name IS NOT NULL
OR Name <> ''

Comment: "Select Name, Age from Members where Name IS NOT NULL OR Name <> ''" would return rows where name = '' on DBMSs that treat NULL and '' differently, because for them '' IS NOT NULL!

Comment: ALL rdbms's SHOULD treat NULL as different from a zero length string because they *are* different.  An empty string means you do have a string there, but it's zero length, a Null means an absence of data.  This is not optional, it's in the specification of how RDBMS' work

Comment: Totally agree with you, Oracle is WRONG here.  In its defence however, it has been around longer than the SQL standard!

Answer (score 0):

T-SQL

```
select name,age from members where COALESCE(name, '') <> ''
```

Comment: What's the improvement over " name is not null and name <> '' " ?